# How to remove HTML5 video player navigation button

Tags: css, html, video

I am using HTML5 video player to play video constantly.Every thing is fine except the video navigation button displaying at the last of the video screen as soon as the mouse cursor moves over the video. I want to remove or hide it but not getting how to do it ..
Here is the HTML for the Video used..

```
<video id='video-player' autoplay="autoplay" loop  preload='metadata' controls>
<source src="Video/1.MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Please help me to remove the navigation bar from the last ..Thanks..

Comment: can we see this live?

Comment: @RST Video i have added from local directory so not possible to show.By navigation bar i mean the one by which we can pause the video or forward or backward , increase / decrease volume etc ..I want to hide this bar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disabled controls via Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('video-player').controls = false
```

Or simply remove `controls` attribute:

```
<video id='video-player' autoplay="autoplay" loop preload="metadata">
    <source src="Video/1.MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: @Pritishkumar You're welcome. Set this answer as accepted if your problem is solved, to close this question.