# remove HTML5 video player menu button

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I wanted to remove the menu button ('kebab' (three vertical dots)) from the video controls of the HTML5 video tag.

I had searched a lot about this and found a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839359/how-to-remove-html5-video-player-navigation-button) but in the accepted answer the user gives instructions to remove all the controls but I don't want to remove all the controls but menu button as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You should use two attributes:

1. disablePictureInPicture: a boolean flag
2. controlslist: a string list

Write this and you won't have three dots menu:

```html
<video controls disablePictureInPicture controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate">
```

Comment: this solved the problem, should be accepted

Comment: I'm happy that my answer has helped you, @provance

Answer (score -1):

There is an experimental attribute for video tag called controlslist. It can help you remove the menu button wich contains the download link

You can use it like this :

```
<video controls controlslist="nodownload">
    <source src="Video/1.MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Find more details here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score -1):

This way, it removes the small menu ("More Options") from the video without losing the video controls.

```
<video
  controls
  controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"
  autoPlay
  onTimeUpdate={handleTimeUpdate}
  disablePictureInPicture
>
 <source src={url} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```