# Hiding the controls in video

Tags: html, html5-video

Although there is no controls attribute in HTML, I cannot hide the bottom controls of video, it appears when pointer comes on the video.

This is the code in media.liquid of shopify theme:

```
  <div class="product-media product-media--video product-media--{{ media.id }} product-media--frame"
      data-video-type="shopify"
      data-enable-video-looping="{{ section.settings.enable_video_looping }}"
      style="padding-top: {{ 1 | divided_by: media.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%; ">
    {{ media | video_tag: autoplay: true, loop: true, mute: true, class: 'media-video', image_size: '600x600' }}

  </div>
```

This is the HTML output of the code:

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" mute="true" class="media-video" muted="muted" preload="metadata"  xxx </video>
```

As you can see, there is no controls in html.

I want to make the video autoplay with mute and loop attributes, at the same time without showing any controls.

No problem with making the video autoplay, mute and loop.

I've tried to put css code "pointer-events:none", it worked but when I scroll down to the under the video in the page, and then scroll up, the video stops playing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove HTML5 video player navigation button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839359/how-to-remove-html5-video-player-navigation-button)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Because the answers on that page, tells to remove "controls".. But in my case, there is already no "controls". Despite that, still bottom controls appears when I hover my mouse on the video.

Comment: What about this one:
https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/prestige-theme-video-as-image-how-to-make-it-autoplay-and-hide/m-p/1275369#M62962

Comment: @UmutCanYıldırım can you make a demo page showing the problem in action? If the source code really has no `controls` listed then where would the `<video>` element get that from??? Also you are using the built-in browser player and not some customised media player, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add **controls: controls,**

```html
{{ media | video_tag: autoplay: true, loop: true, mute: true, controls: controls, class: 'media-video', image_size: '600x600' }}
```